# Null pointer exeception in ListAdapter

Tags: android

I want to display Data in List View but I got Error Null Pointer Exception run time in line

```
fList.setAdapter(la);
```

My code is here List is complete printing in Log
Thanks

```
public class Forfattere extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.forfattere);
    ListView fList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Author_list);
    ArrayList<String> a = DBlistbookfestival.getAuthorName();
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        aList.add(a.get(i));
        Log.v("all_data",a.get(i));
    }
    ListAdapter1 la = new ListAdapter1(this, R.id.Author_list, aList);
    fList.setAdapter(la);
 }

private class ListAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  // --CloneChangeRequired
    private ArrayList<String> mList;  // --CloneChangeRequired
    public ListAdapter1(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<String> list) { // --CloneChangeRequired
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.mList = list;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        try{
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_radio, null);     // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
        }
        final String listItem = mList.get(position);    // --CloneChangeRequired                
        if (listItem != null) {
            ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView111) ).setText(listItem);
        }}catch(Exception e){

        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: just a note: you shouldn't give R.id.Author_list in the adapter as a textViewResourceId. textViewResourceId is the id that is used to put in your data if you don't override getView(); see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int)

Comment: please show us the error log stack trace, why and at which line the error appeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try now :

```
public class Forfattere extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListAdapter1 la = null;
ListView fList = null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.forfattere);
    fList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Author_list);
    ArrayList<String> a = DBlistbookfestival.getAuthorName();
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        aList.add(a.get(i));
        Log.v("all_data",a.get(i));
    }
    la = new ListAdapter1(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aList);
    fList.setAdapter(la);
 }

private class ListAdapter1 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  // --CloneChangeRequired
    private ArrayList<String> mList;  // --CloneChangeRequired
    public ListAdapter1(Context context, int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<String> list) { // --CloneChangeRequired
        super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        this.mList = list;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View view = convertView;
        try{
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.custom_radio, null);     // --CloneChangeRequired(list_item)
        }
        final String listItem = mList.get(position);    // --CloneChangeRequired                
        if (listItem != null) {
            ( (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView111) ).setText(listItem);
        }}catch(Exception e){

        }
        return view;
    }
}   
}
```

In the following I used android default list item as you didn't declare one.

```
la = new ListAdapter1(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aList);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem come from this line :

```
ListView fList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Author_list);
```

The findviewbyid return null, this means that there is no element in your layout R.layout.forfattere with the id R.id.Author_list.
Look in your layout to see if the listview has this Id.

Answer (score 0):

your listview could be null if findbyId doesnt find your listview R.id.Author_list in the layout.